# convergence of improper integral with parameter p

Tags: real-analysis

How does one prove that the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^p}{1+x}dx
\end{equation}
converges for all $-1<p<0$?

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: I know that when you look at small $x$ that $x^p$ will only be integrable if $p>-1$

Comment: @G.Fougeron forgot to @ you

Comment: This is a good start, and il will handle the problem arround $x=0$. What about $x=+\infty $?

Comment: around $+\infty$ $x^p$ will go to infinity if $p>0$ and to $0$ if $p<0$

Comment: Great! Unless I'm mistaken, you now have all the keys to anwer your problem for yourself. If not, can you detail what your final difficulties are?